# Android padding text to the left doesnt work

Tags: android, xml, padding

Im Trying to padding the text on my buttom to the left, so I can fit a simple small image before the text, but for some reason it doesnt work, and part from the text is on the icon image.

here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttons_bg">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btPachuApps"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Pachu Apps Page" 
            style="@style/ButtonText"
            android:background="@drawable/button_apps"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="64dp"/>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFartSoundsProFree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sounds_list"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="64dp"
            android:text="Fart Sounds Pro Free" 

            style="@style/ButtonText"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFartSoundsPro"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Fart Sounds Pro"
            android:background="@drawable/button_sounds_list"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="64dp"
            style="@style/ButtonText"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFartPianoFree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Fart Piano Free"
            android:background="@drawable/button_piano_list" 
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="64dp"
            style="@style/ButtonText"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btFartPiano"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Fart Piano Pachu"
            android:background="@drawable/button_piano_list"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="64dp"
            style="@style/ButtonText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is the result :
[image]

Comment: Try to remove `android:padding="10dp"` attributes from Button views.

Comment: Post your code that you defined @style/ButtonText

Comment: I've post my comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `android:padding="10dp"` attributes from Button views.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `android:gravity="left"` in the button xml, the default is `android:gravity="center"`, Add padding after this.